how to use declared variable of query outside the cfquery
below is the Query which I am using.
<cfquery name="insert">
    Declare @time int;
    set @time =DATEDIFF(ww,'#Form.StartDate#' , '#Form.EndDate#');
    insert into timehistory()
    values(1,@time)
    </cfquery>

I need to use the @time variable value outside the cfquery. I need to display the value of the declared variable in cfcatch if any error occurs

First, you can use a ColdFusion variable instead of an SQL variable.  Your real problem though is datatypes.  Datediff returns an integer which you are trying to use as a SmallDateTime.

Or I think at the end of your query, you can add select @time to use it outside of the query, but if the query errors, then that likely wouldn't have executed yet.

You should guard your query against SQL injections by wrapping the date variables in <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="timestamp">.

You could always declare the variable outside of SQL.
<cfset time = DateDiff("ww", Form.StartDate , Form.EndDate)>

And then use this variable in your SQL
<cfquery name="insert">
   insert into timehistory()
    values(1,<CFQUERYPARAM VALUE="#time#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">)
</cfquery>

You can reuse your time variable as long as you want from there

I don't want to use the ColdFusion variable inside the cfquery. I need that Query variable value to be used for other cffif condition. So to do that I need to assign Query variable value to ColdFusion variable

@sangeetabhat You can always add an OUTPUT statement to your query to return the value to your query variable.

INSERT INTO ... 
OUTPUT INSERTED.columnNameYouWantOutput
VALUES (...)

You would then use the query name to get the time variable. 
It would be something like insert.columnNameYouWantOutput
However, it would make more sense to use a coldfusion declared variable if you want to use this variable in and outside of queries.
